# Convergence in total distribution distance in the Random Walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: references, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

I'm searching for a proof of the convergence in total distribution distance of the transition probabilities of a Markov chain generated by the Random Walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to its stationary distribution.

I'm aware of a more general result for aperiodic irreducible Markov chains on a state space with a countably generated $\sigma$-algebra, but I would like to know if there is a simpler proof available for the special case described above.